# What happened to Maria and Mamoru?

Tags: from-the-new-world

I know that Maria and Mamoru

> escaped the village and erased their tracks, making it impossible for even their own friends to locate them. The Bakenezumi (I do not know the canon transliteration) even assisted their escape by preparing fake remains for the villagers to find, so as to convince them of Maria and Mamoru's death.

However, the Bakenezumi are later shown to have possession of

> their daughter.

How is this possible? Could it be that Maria and Mamoru

> were captured by Squealer and forced to have a child?

In fact, the ethics committee later commented that

> the remains they found matched entirely to the DNA records of the village. Does that mean that the remains really belonged to Maria and Mamoru, and they were killed after they were deemed to be of no use?

Does the novel explain this? I apologize if i jump to paranoid conclusions, but this possibility sounds too scary.

Comment: Is it necessary to have all of this in spoiler blocks? I don't know the show so I don't know what would actually be spoilers, but it's kind of hard to read the question like this.

Comment: I think it is justified, since the nature of the question itself is a spoiler. Hence, only people who have (nearly) completed the series should be reading it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Comment: @kuwaly they pretty much give the overarching plot and the twist away, so yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it was not explicitly stated in the Anime. The following sequence of events was strongly implied and was part of Squealer's master plan.

1. Squealer helps Maria and Mamoru escape. Furthermore, he lets them stay and live with the colony.
2. Squealer waits for (or sweet-talks) Maria and Mamoru into having a child.
3. Once the child is born, Squealer (and/or his fellow rats) kills Maria and Mamoru.
4. They take the child and raise him/her. ("him" in the Novel, "her" in the Anime)
5. Squealer then takes the bones of Maria and Mamoru and gives them to the ethics committee.

When Squealer says that he will prepare fake remains for the villagers to find and that it will "take some time". He really means the *actual* remains of Maria and Mamoru and that it will "take some time" for them to have a child.

---

The sole purpose of this was to get a human child that could be raised into an Akki* and used against humans in Squealer's pursuit of world domination.

<sub>*I use Akki for short. But they really aren't. In reality, the children raised by the rats will believe themselves to be rats, thus attack inhibition and death-feedback will apply to rats instead of humans.</sub>

Comment: Is this strongly implied in the novel? I think I am going to cry now, by the way

Comment: I dunno. I didn't read the novel. But yeah, when I realized this I was like... wow... holy s​h​i​t... It was almost too obvious.

Comment: So your answer does not have official evidence. I agree that it is strongly implied that Squealer killed them to obtain their bones. However, I think what happened between Maria and Mamoru's escape and the obtaining of their child is uncertain enough to prevent such complete conclusions.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure there *is* an official reference. The details of Maria and Mamoru's escape and their death are likely intentionally left to the imagination of the viewer. That's part of what makes this show so powerful and thought-provoking.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that everything said and implied make sense (story most likely don't imply anything without a purpose), we could even propose a darker possibility.

While it's obvious that they were both killed, we can't be sure about when. I would say the rats could have used brain surgery as they did for their queen to dispose of Maria after she went pregnant. (It's implied "what if they did it to human ?") We don't know if the council got the full squeletal or not. If not, they could have disposed of some of the body parts without killing them in order to give evidences to the council before the 10 month needed to give birth.

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty obvious that Maria and Mamoru are dead if the etheics comittee found the remains had their DNA in it.. Not to mention that squeeler managed to take their child from them..

Answer (score 0):

The (short/long) answer. Maria and Mamoru stayed in squealers colony. In the time that they stayed there, they began to get closer to one another. Since the child is about 9 years old, they must have been together for just about three years. I’m not entirely sure how long they stayed in squealers colony, but from the manga and the implications of the anime. Maria and Mamoru clearly had a child, and weren’t entirely trusting of squealers colony.From what was said in the manga. Mamoru, at the time, wasn’t there to protect Maria after she had her child and was tricked and killed. Upon Mamoru’s return, he was also killed and their child was stolen by Squealer. By the end, Maria and Mamoru make there way to the heaven kotatsu with Shun & Reiko. After a few years Messiah (Maria & Mamoru’s Child), arrives in heaven and sits down in the Kotatsu with his cold mother.

In the end, they all joke in heaven about how long it’ll take for Saki to come join them.

Note: this is an Omake added at the end of the final chapter.

Answer (score -3):

For me they did to them what they did to their queen. 
Saki asked to Satoru in the anime *if they do something like this to a human* (and give up on questioning). But I don't understand why in the end she neither mentions it when talking with Squealer. When it is said that they are really dead, she should have realized that squealer was involved.